# Filesystem speed shaper for Linux

Tags: linux, performance

There is an [`iprelay`](http://packages.debian.org/en/sid/iprelay) (or [`ip_relay`](http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/)) package to shape TCP bandwidth, and it is really useful to test how stuff works on slow connections.

Is there something similar to `iprelay`, which will allow me to shape filesystem write (and / or read, independently) speed? Preferably, just for some directory tree that I run my tests against, so that everything else is still fast. (Note that it is for developer machine testing / debugging only, I do not need it to be secure, to do load balancing and other production stuff.)

I'm thinking about using `iprelay` with `sshfs` or something, but it seems to me a bit too convoluted. Any better methods out there?

Comment: Seems related: http://serverfault.com/questions/211225/simulating-slow-filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out blkio and cgroups:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ioband/wiki/blkio-cgroup

There is also an earlier variant for this, only using pids:
http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Dm-band_Block_IO_Bandwidth_Controller