# simulate slow hdd in kvm

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

Can i simulate a slow hdd in a KVM guest? I need to test what happens with an app when it runs o a slow server (actually a server with the filesystem mounted over nfs).

Related to this, I've found [Simulating slow filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/211225/simulating-slow-filesystem), but the response either suggests mounting over network and using iptables to limit bandwidth, or using virtualBox. I'd like to use KVM without weird over-the-network mounts.

Comment: Possibly this http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/DiskIOLimits

Comment: @HBruijn sounds like what i need, but if i understand correctly this is in a development branch, not in the main kvm install I have on my server? can i use this without recompiling kvm(+qemu)?

Comment: I don't know. That other approach appears [cgroups](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cgroups.html) and the [blkio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt) controller kernel module.

Comment: yeah, in Ubuntu 12.04 this would imply that i need to get root on that server and run some commands as root... I'd still prefer something simpler, but you should post your comment as an answer in the meantime

Comment: Disk I/O limits have been in for a while, but not quite _that_ long. Why are you using Ubuntu? and an older version at that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: its not my server, i cannot control the host. I could probably run some commands as root under supervision, but i cannot do radical changes on the server.